c# entityframework code DbContext.Add does not seem to be inserting non-key columns. why?
This code is EntityFramework Code on .NET-8.
expt_table consists of a key and non-key column.
On an empty table, tried to do DbContext.Add of a single record.
namespace expt;

using NUnit.Framework;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("expt_table")]
[PrimaryKey(nameof(userName))]
public class DbPageCompleted {

    [Column("user_name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string? userName {get; set;}

    [Column("last_update_time")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime? lastUpdateTime;
}

public class ExptContext : DbContext {


    public DbSet<DbPageCompleted> pageCompletions { get; set; }

    protected string connectionStr()
    {
        var connStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLCONNSTR_DbConn");
        if (connStr == null) throw new NoDbConnection();
        return connStr;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string? connStr = connectionStr();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connStr);
    }

    public static ExptContext dbContext = new ExptContext();
}

[TestFixture]
public class ExptTests {


    DbPageCompleted dbPageCompleted = new DbPageCompleted {
        userName = "test@localhost.com",
        lastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
    };

    [Test]
    public void Expt() {
        ExptContext dbContext = ExptContext.dbContext;
        dbContext.pageCompletions.Add(dbPageCompleted);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

gives an exception
  ----> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'last_update_time', table 'asubio1-db.dbo.expt_table'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The project file for this code is
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Have tried a few variants, but have not been able to get past this.
Is there something basic I am missing?

Why does lastUpdateTime  have type DateTime? (Which is really Nullable<DateTime>) and also have the [Required] attribute? lastUpdateTime should probably be declared as public DateTime lastUpdateTime { get; set; } = default;. You're going to run into the same issue with userName too.

lastUpdateTime is possibly genuinely null for some entity, so your code makes the validation a bit whacky. What I've noticed is that lastUpdateTime is only a field instead of a property, and I was quite sure EF could not pick up fields.

@phuzi, I made the fields mandatory, and this has not helped. I will modify the question.

@DevilSuichiro - Thanks, making the field as a property did help

Answer is from @DevilSuichiro
The updateTime field has to be made into a Property by placing a {get; set;}
The correct code will be
[Table("expt_table")]
[PrimaryKey(nameof(userName))]
public class DbPageCompleted {

    [Column("user_name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string? userName {get; set;}

    [Column("last_update_time")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime? lastUpdateTime {get; set;}
}

Obviously, once one knows what to look for. Hopefully, it will help others.
The optional ? in DateTime? and string? in the question does not cause the problem, as long as a value is assigned before the Add.
I added it there to avoid warnings from C # about requiring constructors.
